# Install grails 1.3.7 (or any other specific version) using Homebrew

Tags: grails, homebrew

How do you install a specific version of a formulae, in Homebrew? - in my case; Grails 1.3.7

Comment: Btw, Grails is distibuted as a Zip file, you can download any specific version and extract it anywhere in your system. Just it. And you can start using it, without any extra steps. It's also helpful when you want to have different versions.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3987683/320399

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Update:

As pointed out by akst, homebrew has removed the `versions` command so this original method is no longer feasible.

If you really want to, you can still use `brew log grails` in place of `brew versions grails` to find the git SHA for an old version of Grails. The formula is now also in a deeper directory structure so I would recommend using `find . -name grails.rb -execdir git checkout <YOUR SHA HERE> {} \;`

However, I recommend using the fantastic [SDKMAN!](http://sdkman.io/) for managing versions of Grails (and other languages/frameworks!).

### Old Answer:

Go to your brew base,

```
cd $(brew --prefix)
```

list the versions of grails,

```
brew versions grails
```

select the version you want (1.3.7)

```
git checkout 232acd0 $(brew --prefix)/Library/Formula/grails.rb
```

and now install like normal,

```
brew install grails
```

which will install version 1.3.7

Comment: @akst thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the answer with a note and possible alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Rob Brinkman offers a bit more detail on this approach: http://blog.jdriven.com/2012/09/quick-tip-installing-a-specific-grails-version-on-os-x-using-homebrew/

*Paraphrasing here:*

```
brew unlink grails
brew versions grails
cd `brew --prefix` 
git checkout <some hash> <path to formula, i.e. /usr/local/Library/Formula/grails.rb>
brew install grails # install grails
git checkout -- /usr/local/Library/Formula/grails.rb # reset formula
```